# How to use NSTimeInterval in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to use `NSTimeInterval`in Swift 3 but I can't. It seems to exist only in Swift 2.

How can I use NSTimeInterval in Swift 3?

Thanks in advance for your ideas and solutions!

Comment: Use TimeInterval https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timeinterval

Comment: Downvotes ... downvotes. The guy said stupid statement. Ok. Should we really crusify him?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As with many other type identifiers, the `NS` prefix has been stripped off from `NSTimeInterval` in Swift 3. So, you can just use `TimeInterval`.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work, but how I should use it if I want something like this? var lastUptadeTime = NSTimeInterval = 0 @stefan

Comment: @HessianMad TimeInterval is just a typeAlias: `typealias TimeInterval = Double`

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @HessianMad `var timeInterval: TimeInterval = 0` would work

Comment: @HessianMad: as the others said. Btw, to be nit-picking, semantically a `lastUpdateTime` is not a time duration but a point in time, so I would either write `var lastUpdateTime: Time` or `var lastUpdateAge: TimeInterval` (or similar) :-)